# three.js tween object to front of camera

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've got an object that is tweening (almost) nicely to the front of the camera using WestLangleys answer to another question:

```
    var pLocal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -10 );
    var pWorld = pLocal.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
    var target = pWorld.sub( camera.position ).normalize();

    var tweenMove = new TWEEN.Tween(object.position).to(target, 2000)
```

The next part I'm struggling with is to get the object to remain a certain distance from the camera (adjusting the z = -10 has no effect), as when it finishes the tween it disappears (too close to camera).

Camera.near is 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var pLocal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 10 );

var target = pLocal.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );

var tweenMove = new TWEEN.Tween( object.position ).to( target, 2000 );
```