# Three set object in front of camera in a dolly

Tags: 3d, three.js, quaternions, 360-virtual-reality

I'm placing an object in front of the camera using

```
        var dist = -100;
        var vec = new THREE.Vector3( 0,  0, dist );
        vec.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
        object.position.copy( vec );
        object.lookAt(camera.position);
```

This works really well.

I'm now having to rotate the camera (its for a VR video player) to set it's starting position and to do that and still work with WebVR boilerplate, I add the video to a dolly object and rotate that.

```
    dolly = new THREE.Group();
    dolly.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    scene.add( dolly );

    camera.up.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    dolly.add( camera );
```

And the object is now not in front of the camera. I'm trying to apply the dolly rotation to the vector to account for that angle.

```
        var rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion( camera.quaternion, camera.rotation.order );
        rotation.y += dolly.rotation.y;
        var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(rotation, camera.rotation.order);
        vec.applyQuaternion( quat );
```

This mostly works when  the camera is particular angles but sometimes not and the object is also rotated on it's x axis.

I assume   `rotation.y += dolly.rotation.y`; is wrong but I'm not sure of a better way to merge the numbers.

Comment: You could just add your object directly to the `camera` object... `camera.add(object);` This will place the object within camera space, and it will follow the camera's movements and rotations automatically.

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01, yes I was doing this before but the item has selectable elements so the camera needs to be able to look at different parts. I'll go back to this if I have to I'm just trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WestLangleys answer on here
[three.js tween object to front of camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346031/three-js-tween-object-to-front-of-camera?rq=1)

Answered my question

```
      var pLocal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, dist );

        var target = pLocal.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );

        object.position.copy( target );
        object.lookAt(camera.position);
```